# Flex, Java, BlazeDS and config file for my application

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, shared-objects

I'm programming Rich web applications with Flex and Java on Flex Builder 3 using blazeDS and SharedObjects.
Now I need that my program will use configuration file.
so, I need that my Java class will read it at the first time but the default path of java to read and write files is c:\program files\Flex Builder 3 and not my application directory inside the tomcat webapps directory
How can I read the config file from the java class without write the path hardcoded in the java?

Answer (score 0):

The `SharedObjecs` should only be written and read by your Flex application!

For accessing the file system (on the server side) from Java you can use an environment variable. 
Create and/or edit the `setenv.sh|bat` file in your `tomcat/bin` like this:

```
# setenv.sh
export MYAPP_HOME=/etc/myapp

# setenv.bat
set MYAPP_HOME=c:\myapp
```